# Are any of the Marvel Phase Four TV shows necessary to understand Spider-Man: No Way Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

*Spider-Man: No Way Home* delves into the Multiverse, bringing together different versions of villains from various iterations of Spider-Man. I'm only tangentially aware of the current crop of Marvel TV shows (*WandaVision*, *Loki*, *What If...?* and *Hawkeye*), but I know that at least some of these touch on alternate realities as well.

Are any of them required to make sense of the *Spider-Man: No Way Home* plotline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. As your question suggests, the story does involve alternate realities, but you really only need to be familiar with the general principle of a multiverse. I didn't notice any significant references to the Phase Four TV shows, beyond the mere acknowledgement that a multiverse exists.

As long as you've seen the following MCU movies...

- *Captain America: Civil War* (2016)
- *Doctor Strange* (2016)
- *Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017)
- *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018)
- *Avengers: Endgame* (2019)
- *Spider-Man: Far From Home* (2019)

... and the following Sony Pictures movies...

- *Spider-Man* (2002)
- *Spider-Man 2* (2004)
- *Spider-Man 3* (2007)
- *The Amazing Spider-Man* (2012)
- *The Amazing Spider-Man 2* (2014)
- *Venom* (2018)
- *Venom: Let There Be Carnage* (2021)

... you should be fine. Even some of these (like the two *Venom* films) aren't necessarily *essential* viewing, but I would consider them *recommended* viewing, if you want to fully 'get' the major references and nods in this film.

Tricky to go into much more detail without spoiling the movie and/or the Phase Four TV shows.

Comment: The post-credits scene will seem more familiar if you've seen *What If...?*, particularly episode 4.

Comment: I suppose, but that was technically a trailer for a future film, rather than a 'scene' as such. I would recommend watching _What If...?_ episode 4 before that film comes out, but I don't think it's necessary for this one. I doubt it'll even be essential viewing for that film, actually, but it'd be a bonus.

Comment: Watching, or at least being aware of, the Netflix Daredevil show will also help understand one scene.

Comment: You don't need all of those to understand the plotline. The essentials are all laid out in the film itself, especially if you have basic cultural knowledge of major Spider-Man stories.

I haven't seen the ASMs or Venom movies and the only confusion I felt was in the mid-credits scene. Any other references I missed were unessential. The only who-was-that? reference my non-comics-wonk wife asked for clarification on was not from the shows listed here.

Comment: @Arcy It's not possible for me to have seen it without having seen ASM1+2, so I may be wrong, but I felt there was significant resolution of events from ASM2 that resonated because I knew that film, and wouldn't have really hit otherwise.

Comment: @Tony Meyer - I think just being familiar with Daredevil as a character -- whether it's the version from the TV show, the Ben Affleck movie, or the comics -- is sufficient to understand that scene.

Comment: @Arcy - True, you don't need to watch all of those to understand the main plot. But you won't have the proper context for various references if you haven't seen those films.

Comment: Having seen NWH without having seen everything on the list and not feeling left out, I'd call that a suggested list not a required one. NWH does a great job of setting things up itself without requiring (though rewarding) pre-knowledge. The big ASM2 event hit very well without seeing ASM2. I knew the backstory from general Spidey-knowledge. My wife caught it from the film without any explanation of who-was-who or why that scene was significant beyond what was on screen. I wouldn't recommend seeing NWH before the other MCU Spider-Man movies and maybe Doctor Strange. The rest are bonus.

Comment: @Arcy: I agree with you. My gf only watched the MCU spiderman movies and a couple of other MCU movies and enjoyed NWH a lot, more than I did. Can you make a more minimal list? I would write one but I saw many MCU movies, so I may miss something important.

Comment: @Arcy - You may not have felt left out, but that doesn't mean you fully 'got' everything. I can't really explain what you've might've missed without spoiling the movie. I did however edit my answer to clarify that some of these films can be considered recommended viewing, rather than required viewing. The question wasn't strictly asking about which _films_ were required or recommended viewing anyway. I provided a recommended list as a bonus.

Answer (score 7):

**There is no minimum required viewing.** You can watch [*Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10872600/) by itself and understand the main plot. The film explains everything very clearly for the casual viewer who has not seen any other comic book movie. However, this viewer would be missing out greatly! You will only get full enjoyment if you are familiar with the entire Spider-Man film franchise, as it is primarily designed for such fans.

Here is what I consider **recommended viewing** to truly appreciate the film, feel the emotional scenes and understand the audience's cheering:

- [*Spider-Man* (2002)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145487/)
- [*Spider-Man 2* (2004)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0316654/)
- [*Spider-Man 3* (2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0413300/)
- [*The Amazing Spider-Man* (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/)
- [*The Amazing Spider-Man 2* (2014)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1872181/)
- [*Spider-Man: Homecoming* (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2250912/)
- [*Spider-Man: Far From Home* (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6320628/)

The film also has content to appeal to "superfans". Here is what I consider **optional viewing** if you want to understand *absolutely everything*, including all references, jokes, easter eggs, cameos and mid/post-credits scenes: (potential spoilers)

> - [Spider-Man internet memes (I won't say which ones)](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/raimiposting)
> - [*Iron Man* (2008)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/)
> - [*The Incredible Hulk* (2008)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800080/)
> - [*Infowars Nightly News with Alex Jones* (2011)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2111748/)
> - [*Daredevil* (2015)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3322312/)
> - [*Captain America: Civil War* (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/)
> - [*Doctor Strange* (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211837/)
> - [*Avengers: Infinity War* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/)
> - [*Venom* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270797/)
> - [*Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4633694/)
> - [*Avengers: Endgame* (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/)
> - [*WandaVision* (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9140560/)
> - [*What If...?* (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10168312/)
> - [*Venom: Let There Be Carnage* (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7097896/)
> - [*Hawkeye* (2021)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10160804/)

Comment: Too scared to click the spoiler block, but thank you for this. As soon as I get to watch the movie, I will see about moving the tick.

Comment: The spoiler block is just a list of movies, so there's not really much to fear by clicking it

Comment: "Superfans", pfhht. Where is my Nicholas Hammond cameo.

Comment: @TransparentBlue Good answer